# @Value not inject data from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I will show you a little code and then I will ask a question.

**SendEmail.java**

```
package com.goode;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SendEmail {

  @Value("${email.username}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${email.password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${email.fullAddress}")
  private String fullAddress;

  @Value("${email.host}")
  private String host;

  @Value("${email.port}")
  private String port;

  public boolean send(String toEmail, String subject, String message){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
          }
        });

    try {
      Message createMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
      createMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fullAddress));
      createMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
          InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
      createMessage.setSubject(subject);
      createMessage.setText(message);
      Transport.send(createMessage);

      return true;

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
  {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer o = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    o.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
    return o;
  }
}
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
package com.goode.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = {"com.goode.repository"})
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.goode.service", "com.goode.repository", "com.goode.controller", "com.goode.business", "com.goode"})
public class RootConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.goode.business");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());

    return factory;
  }

  private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;
  }
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
  }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GoodE
jdbc.username = postgres
jdbc.password = postgres
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
email.username = xx //I replce real data to xx just to this post
email.password = xx
email.fullAddress = xx@xx.com
email.host = xx
email.port = xx
```

When I try call a **send** method from SendEmail console shows error:

> *java.lang.NullPointerException: null*

in line:

> props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

So annotation @Value doesn't inject any value from application.properties to private variable in SendEmail. Why is that?

In **RootConfig.java** I used *@Autowired*, *Environment* and *@PropertySource* but I read somewhere that you can use @PropertySource only in @Configuration class so I tried find another way -> I found @Value, but I have no idea why data from application.properties are not injecting to variable. 
I put **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** in SendEmail because I read it's necessary. I am not sure this is the right place for it but placing this in another class e.g. RootConfig didn't help.
May you have any advice where should I search for bug?

Comment: application.properties absolutely would pick up that key.  Can you show us that file?

Comment: Added to main post. I am not sure this is a problem because data to connection to database loads fine.

Comment: Okay - thanks for providing that.  Typically one doesn't put spaces between the property key and the equals sign.  Given that this is the only line you noticed the NPE, when you go to debug this, do you see any other properties not making their way across?

Comment: Maybe try to put those properties in a separate properties file and load that with `@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence.properties"})`. See if that helps.

Comment: Try removing those three lombok annotations from the Component. I suspect it is ignoring some Value annotations because it sees the all-args constructor or the setters created with @Data, and those are not going to have the Value annotations on them.

Comment: Ok, so, I debugged this, non of this 5 values don't inject. Tried create new file persistence.properties and use @PropertySource and then PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer -> same error for both. Removed lombok annotations and this still not helped.

Comment: Please try to move `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` from SendEmail.java to RootConfig.java (initialize bean in class with @Configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:
`@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })` 
is unnecessary because all values from `application.properties` are picked up by default. That being said, you also don't need `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` for that.

Make sure that when calling your `send` method, that you are not instantiating your `SendEmail` class as `new SendEmail()` because that will not work as `@Value` works only inside of the spring application context.

You must either do an `@Autowired` or constructor injection (the latter being recommended).

Also this:
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.goode.service", "com.goode.repository", "com.goode.controller", "com.goode.business", "com.goode"})`
Can be replaced by this:
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.goode.*"})`

Comment: Works perfectly. Good to know that @Value can be injected only inside of the spring application context. Thanks for other advices too.